# Would the users be able to understand "emp" as "employee" if I have space constraints?

Tags: text, space-constraints

I have to show employee status in a place but I have a space constraint.

Will the users be able to understand "emp" as "employee"?

Comment: You can always use a tooltip to expand "emp" to "employee"

Comment: What is the target audience? How old are they? What language do they speak? Have you actually spoken to any of them to see if they would understand it? What user research have you done here? What context will this be shown in? Just generally asking if people know what 'emp' means isn't answerable, you need to provide full context here to be able to solicit full answers.

Comment: Please have a read of [this guide on how to ask constructive questions](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) as several of your recent questions have fallen short of the ideal standards of questions for StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on two factors:

1. Your app type
2. End user

Say your application is a payroll and users are employees, then it is well understood by the end users as they are familiar with short terms.

But, if the same application is used by other category of people then , they may not get the short words. Here emp to employee is a common word so i think most of them will get it, if you have same thing in medical terms then it would be difficult for end user to understand the same.

In that case use something like tooltip as Chris says. or other glossary building technique like that of wikipedia!